# Is max() of a generator building a list-like object or is it working more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, generator, memory-efficient

Let's say I have directory in which I have filenames with the names `'filename_1'`, `'filename_2'`, etc. and have a generator `models_paths` which I use to find the newest number:

```
mypath = 'my/path/filename'
models_paths = Path(mypath).parent.glob(Path(mypath).name + '*')
number_newest = max(int(str(file_path).split('_')[-1]) for file_path in models_paths)
```

I would like to know whether `max` is building a list-like data structure or whether it is using an algorithm like

```
number_newest = None
for file_path in models_paths:
    number_current = int(str(file_path).split('_')[-1])
    number_newest = number_current if number_newest is None else max(number_current, number_newest)
```

In other words: Am I losing processing efficiency and/or memory efficiency if I write

```
mypath = 'my/path/filename'
models_paths = Path(mypath).parent.glob(Path(mypath).name + '*')
models_paths = list(models_paths)
number_newest = max(int(str(file_path).split('_')[-1]) for file_path in models_paths)
```

?

Comment: You pass generator to `max()` function so it consume it, no additional lists created for that. You're not losing processing efficiency, but you could slightly boost your code if you'd use `int(str(file_path).rsplit("_", 1)[-1]))`. Also you don't need to cast `models_paths` to `list`, you can just remove this line of code. Also you can use `max()` with `key` argument: `max(models_paths, key=lambda x: int(str(x).split('_')[-1]))`.

Comment: Combining previous comment into single code example: `max(models_paths, key=lambda x: int(str(x).rsplit("_", 1)[-1]))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Well, from what you wrote, I would have thought that I am losing efficiency, because the casting to list a) costs time and b) costs extra memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` does not build a list.

This can be demonstrated clearly in this example with a custom object:

```
class Thing:
    
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print(f'creating {x}')
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'destroying {self.x}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{self.x}>'
        

print(max(Thing(i) for i in range(5)))
```

which gives:

```
creating 0
creating 1
destroying 0
creating 2
destroying 1
creating 3
destroying 2
creating 4
destroying 3
<4>
destroying 4
```

As you can see, the `__del__` method is being called on each of the objects as soon as it is decided that it is no longer the object with the maximum value.  This would not be the case if they were being appended to a list.

Contrast with:

```
print(max([Thing(i) for i in range(5)]))
```

which gives:

```
creating 0
creating 1
creating 2
creating 3
creating 4
destroying 3
destroying 2
destroying 1
destroying 0
<4>
destroying 4
```

You can write a (less efficient) equivalent function and show that it does the same thing:

```
def mymax(things):
    empty = True
    for thing in things:
        if empty or (thing > maximum):  # parentheses for clarity only
            maximum = thing
            empty = False
    if empty:
        raise ValueError
    return maximum
```